# Can't resolve "no protocol" in java

Tags: java

Hello everyone I wanted to know how to do `.userAgent()` with URL correctly?

And why people use `.userAgent()`?

And how can I solve the error "no protocol: Google Gmail..." problem

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        
            String str;
            try {
                str = Jsoup.connect("https://google.com").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36").get().text();
                URL a = new URL(str);
                HttpsURLConnection b = (HttpsURLConnection)a.openConnection();
                if(b.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        System.out.println("yes");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("no");
                    return;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
```

Error: `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Google Gmail Google`

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please ask *one question* per post.

Comment: I don't know Jsoup, but https://jsoup.org/ suggests that you use it incorrectly. What you would get into `str` is the docucument retrieved, not an URL; therefore the message is correct (`https://google.com` would be an URL).

You could verfy this with ease by adding a `system.out.println(str);` to your code

Comment: You find the definition of an URL in [RFC1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738)

Comment: For your separate question "why people use .userAgent()" you could research, e.g. for [`[browser-detection] user-agent`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbrowser-detection%5D+user-agent) or see Dev.to: [The importance of use User Agent to Scraping Data](https://dev.to/hhsm95/using-user-agent-to-scraping-data-lli)

Answer (score 1):

Using the wrong URL could be intended or a typo (missing out `www`).

#### Test the HTTP request

For example use curl:

```sh
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36" "https://google.com"
```

results in HTML body response:

```html
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

indicating a HTTP status [301 Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) which usually has a response-header `location` with the new URL where this resource (site) has moved.

When using `-v` option on curl, to get verbose output (including response headers) we got:

```
< HTTP/2 301 
< location: https://www.google.com/
```

#### Use proper URL, not any text scraped from HTML with JSoup

```java
String url = "https://google.com";

String agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36";
str = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(agent).get().text();
System.out.println("Jsoup returned following text from HTML response: " + str)                

URL anotherUrl = new URL(url); // dont use the ext returned by JSoup, use an url string
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) anotherUrl.openConnection();
```

#### How to fix

You could directly use the proper URL: `https://www.google.com/` with `JSoup` and `HttpsURLConnection`.

#### Allow JSoup to follow redirects

JSoup can automatically follow redirects indicated by HTTP response codes `3xx` using builder-method [`followRedirects(boolean)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#followRedirects(boolean)) like:

```java
String url = "https://google.com";

String agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36";
str = Jsoup.connect(url)
           .userAgent(ua)
           .followRedirects(true)  //  allow to follow the location when 3xx
           .get()
           .text();
System.out.println("Jsoup returned following text from HTML response: " + str)
```

This should print out the Google Search page as text (extracted from responded HTML).

Comment: the ".userAgent(ua)" is right?